# Finding the number missing in the sequence

Tags: algorithm, xor

I have been given a list of n integers and these integers are in the range of 1 to n. There are no duplicates in list.But one of the integers is missing in the list.I have to find the missing integer.

```
Example: If n=8
I/P    [7,2,6,5,3,1,8]
O/P    4

I am using a simple concept to find the missing number which is to get the 
sum of numbers 
       total = n*(n+1)/2
And then Subtract all the numbers from sum.
```

But the above method will fail if the sum of the numbers goes beyond maximum allowed integer.

So i searched for a second solution and i found a method as follows:

```
 1) XOR all the elements present in arr[], let the result of XOR be R1.
 2) XOR all numbers from 1 to n, let XOR be R2.
 3) XOR of R1 and R2 gives the missing number.
```

How is this method working?..How is the XOR of R1 and R2 finds the missing integer in the above case?

Comment: How about brute forcing it? Sort the array, check the couple of indexes for which `[n - (n-1)]` does not equal 1.

Comment: Why is there a maximum allowed integer?

Comment: @VoronoiPotato: What if there are 1 billion numbers in the sequence and he's limited to 32-bit integers?

Comment: @Renan because that's slower? And anyway the OP isn't asking for an alternative solution but about why/how the proposed one works.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To answer your question , you just have to remember that

```
A XOR B = C => C XOR A = B
```

and it immediately follows that

```
(PARTIAL SUM) XOR (MISSING ELEMENT) = (TOTAL) => 
(TOTAL) XOR ( PATIAL SUM) = (MISSING ELEMNT)
```

To prove the first property, just write down the XOR truth table:

```
A B | A XOR B
0 0 | 0
0 1 | 1
1 0 | 1
1 1 | 0
```

Truth table in short : if both the bits are same, result of XOR is false, true otherwise.

On an unrelated note, this property of XOR makes it a nice candidate for simple ( but not trivial ) forms of encryption.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you can make your original method work even in the presence of integer overflow (as long as `n` fits in an `int`).

As to the XOR method, observe that `R1 xor M == R2` (where `M` is the missing number). From this it follows that `R1 xor M xor R2 == 0` and therefore `M == R1 xor R2`.

Answer (score 4):

The `XOR` works because every time you `XOR` a bit with `1` you flip it, and every time you `XOR` a bit with `0` it stays the same.  So the result of `XOR`ing all the data save the missing number gives you the 'negative' impression of `XOR`ing all the numbers.  `XOR`ing these two together restores your lost number.

Answer (score 1):

Let's just look at the XOR of the low order bit (LOB) to keep things simple.  Let x be the missing integer.

Each integer in the list contributes a 1 or a zero the LOB of R1 (LOB(R1)).

Each integer in the range contributes a 1 or a zero to the LOB(R2).

Now suppose LOB(R1) == LOB(R2).  Since R2 == R2 XOR x, this can only happen if LOB(x) == 0 == LOB(R1) XOR LOB(R2).  (1 xor 1 = 0, 0 xor 0 = 0)

Or suppose (LOB(R1) == LOB(R2).  This can only happen if LOB(x) == 1 == LOB(R1) XOR LOB(R2)  (1 xor 0 = 1, 0 xor 1 = 1).

But what works for the low order bit works for all of them, because XOR is computed independently, bit by bit.