# Why is (PARTIAL SUM) XOR (MISSING NUMBER) = Total?

Tags: boolean, bitwise-operators, boolean-logic, xor

I've been looking into how to use the XOR operator to solve some classic problems like finding the missing number in a sequence. I understand how XOR achieves this by cancelling out duplicates through its properties (e.g. commutativity, `x ^ x = 0`, `x ^ 0 = x`, etc.)

What I don't understand is this alternative approach in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335587/finding-the-number-missing-in-the-sequence) which says that:

> (PARTIAL SUM) XOR (MISSING ELEMENT) = (TOTAL)

Why is this the case? And does it always work? I did it with pen and paper testing it on sequences of 3's starting from 0 (i.e. `[00, 01, 10]` then `[01, 10, 11]`, etc...) and noticed that this works but breaks down at the sequence `[2, 3, 4]` if we take 3 to be the missing number:
`(2+4) ^ 3 = 5` instead of the actual total 9.

On another note, that same answer states that:

> A XOR B = C => C XOR A = B

What's the logic behind this equivalence?

Comment: In this case the "partial sum" and "total" are really "partial xor" and "total xor"; not "partial addition" and "total addition". That "(partial xor) XOR (missing value) = (total xor)" is just the definition of "partial xor" and "total xor".

Comment: Thank you for this clarification. Now it makes much more sense